# Как выучить js творческому человеку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть js код адаптивного меню на jquery (представьте это один файл)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu-trigger').click(function () {
        $('nav ul').slideToggle(500);
    }); //end slide toggle

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 600) {
            $('nav ul').removeAttr('style');
        }
    }); //end resize
```

Код выполняется построчно и не перескакивает со строки на строку? Помогите понять этот код. Все идет с начала и до конца? по очереди? Если что-то будет не по синтаксису, то будет ошибка?

Есть другой код:

```
var _menu = $("#menu");
var _block = $("#block");
_menu.click(function () {
    _block.toggleClass('lowPosition');
    var nextpos = _block.hasClass('lowPosition') ? '10%' : '4%';
    _block.animate({
        'bottom': nextpos
    }, 300);
});
}); //end ready
```

Как можно манипулировать классом `lowPosition` которого нет? 
`.hasClass` - функция которая проверяет наличие класса, допустим. Мне обязательно это делать? Почему здесь мы проверяем наличие класса, а например в случае с меню `$('nav ul').slideToggle(500);` мы не проверяем есть ли класс nav ul? Как понять эти закономерности?

Если, например, у меня в коде с меню будет та же переменная, что и в коде ниже, что будет? Как понять как мне писать программу (код)?

Если эти 2 кода, что выше, это как 2 разные мысли, но они же находятся в одном файле и как браузер при выполнении не путает их и понимает, что к чему? Нужно ли мне адаптивное меню или ховер при нажатии или слайдер как мне понять, где что начинается и заканчиваться? Это же всё один файл и строка за строкой идет.

Читал об отладчике. Как я понимаю, можно проверить какие данные сейчас в переменной и как они меняются по ходу программы?

Comment: думаю, вам проще всего поискать наставника среди знакомых, который сможет вам уделить достаточно времени, чтобы на пальцах разжёвывать подобные вопросы. ибо, судя по вопросу, их будет очень много, а каждый раз сюда писать будет не результативно

Comment: Соглашусь с комментарием выше. Так же посетите http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour. Вопрос — ответ. Ничего лишнего.

Comment: Всё сложно. Вам нужно понять достаточно абстрактные штуки, и если они плохо ложатся на ваш стиль мышления, вам придётся потрудится. Я бы посоветовал начинать с языка попроще, в котором логика более линейна. Может быть, попробуйте C? (Хотя и в нём есть свои серьёзные сложности, но там всё упирается в понимание указателей.)

Comment: Если дело в мышлении я бы посоветовал почитать http://hpmor.ru/.

Comment: И в любом случае изучение js стоит начинать с изучения js, а jquery пока отложить. Очень сложно объяснить магию jquery если базовых знаний javascript нет.

Comment: нельзя выучить то, что постоянно изменяется :\

Answer (score 2):

> Код выполняется построчно и не перескакивает со строки на строку?

Нет.

> Все идет с начала и до конца? по очереди?

Парсинг - да, исполнение - нет.

> Если что-то будет не по синтаксису, то будет ошибка?

На уровне синтаксиса - да. Но синтаксически корректные конструкции могут быть на самом деле некорректны, о чём станет известно при выполнении.

> Как можно манипулировать классом `lowPosition` которого нет?

А как можно на бумаге рисовать фигуру, которой нет?

> `hasClass` - функция которая проверяет наличие класса

Да.

> Мне обязательно это делать?

Тебе обязательно знать имя человека, чтобы к нему обратиться?

> Почему здесь мы проверяем наличие класса, а например в случае с меню `$('nav ul').slideToggle(500);` мы не проверяем есть ли класс nav ul?

Чтобы бросить листовку в почтовый ящик имена всех его владельцев надо проверять?

> Как понять эти закономерности?

Эм.. Если что-то важно, то оно и используется, а если нет, то нет.

> Если, например, у меня в коде с меню будет та же переменная, что и в коде ниже, что будет?

То её надо будет использовать.

> Как понять как мне писать программу (код)?

Подумать...

> Если эти 2 кода, что выше, это как 2 разные мысли, но они же находятся в одном файле и как браузер при выполнении не путает их и понимает, что к чему?

А как ты различаешь разных людей в одной комнате?

> Нужно ли мне адаптивное меню или ховер при нажатии или слайдер

Тебе виднее.

> как мне понять, где что начинается и заканчиваться?

Да хоть по парным скобкам.
А вообще, ты вроде уже в вопросе привёл куски про меню - нашёл же как-то ;)

> Это же всё один файл и строка за строкой идет.

Заметно. Более того, всё кроме первой и последней строки является телом обработчика завершения загрузки документа.

> Читал об отладчике. Как я понимаю, можно проверить какие данные сейчас в переменной и как они меняются по ходу программы?

Да. Но тебе это не надо ведь?